# ./symfony propel:build-forms not building my plugin forms

Tags: symfony1, propel, symfony-1.4

here is an excerpt of ./symfony propel:build-forms:

```
helloises@helloise:~/github_mira/rainbow_code/phoenix$ ./symfony propel:build-forms
>> propel    generating form classes
>> tokens    /home/helloises/github_mira/rainbow_code/phoenix/lib/form/TrafficChatForumTableForm.class.php
>> tokens    /home/helloises/github_mira/rainbow_code/phoenix/lib/form/ContactSelectionForm.class.php
>> tokens    /home/helloises/github_mira/rainbow_code/phoenix/lib/form/TrafficDemuxTableForm.class.php
>> tokens    /home/helloises/github_mira/rainbow_code/phoenix/lib/form/transferCreditsForm.class.php
>> tokens    /home/helloises/github_mira/rainbow_code/phoenix/lib/form/generateSendDates.class.php
>> tokens    /home/helloises/github_mira/rainbow_code/phoenix/lib/form/TrafficContactTagTableForm.class.php
```

i also have a directory plugins/rainbowcodePlugin where all my rainbowcode stuff resides but how come it does not build anything in the rainbowcode plugin??? can some one explain to me please?

i have a campus_id field in the rcprofiletable and when i build-forms it does not pick up this field??? this field does exist on the table rc_profile_table, it is also contained in the helloises@helloise:~/github_mira/rainbow_code/phoenix/plugins/rainbowCodePlugin/config/schema.yml file????
thank you

Comment: Make sure the plugin is enabled in the ProjectConfiguration class.

Comment: it is :) i have been sitting for days now and none of my forms in the plugin wants to build??? pleeeeease i need urgent help

Comment: Have you tried `symfony doctrine:build --all-classes` ?

Answer (score 1):

Run your command with the **-t** flag, so you can see any errors that might be suppressed.

```
./symfony -t propel:build-forms
```